# add sequential number when insert parameter

Tags: php, mysql, insert, phpmyadmin, auto-increment

I have some difficulty to find a way to make my `ID` value become auto increment in my `phpmyadmin`. Because I want a unique value inside this `ID`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inspec` (
  `recID` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`recID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have parameter like :

```
$myid = "20131022";
$mod = "beta";
```

after insert I want to get the result like:

```
recID              model
201310220001       beta
```

4 digit from behind of `201310220001` is the sequential number (autoincrement) it means this data is the first inputted on 22nd October 2013.How should I do, using PHP script or MYSQL query?

Comment: MySQL is only going to Auto Increment it so i guess you will hit a problem after 1000 entries. So i suggest you do it with PHP. Just out of curiosity, why do you not store the date as a datetime field separately?

Comment: You can use mysql stored procedure to get this effect.

Answer (score 0):

You are way better off by using another column as date indicator. For instance `create_date`. You can use a default value for that that inserts the current date automatically (using a trigger).

Then use a normal auto_increment value for the id.

if you look for the first entry on a specific date you can do

```
select *
from your_table
where create_date = '2013-10-22' 
order by id asc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

add another column `id` which is auto increment

use `SELECT MAX(id) FROM table`;

and then that concatenate that max id with `$myid = "20131022"`